# Parallel activities for one agent

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

Is there a way to have parallel services and/or delays to occur per agent and move on with the activity that takes the longest. For example if I have an agent that can be painted and serviced at the same time, each requiring a different resource pool with different processing times but the agent will move forward when the process that took the longest is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Split block to split your agent into two for the two parallel tasks (Service blocks) and then use a Combine to combine them back again afterwards (with the Combine block outputting the original agent 1).

You can also use RestrictedAreaStart and RestrictedAreaEnd blocks (capacity 1) around the split/combine area to ensure that other agents can't 'jump in' whilst the longest parallel process is still running (but the shorter one has already finished).

Something like the below (with resource pools).

[image: Sample process flow]

Comment: even better :-)

Comment: when i use the split and combine it creates a new agent, how can I make sure the combine block copies the parameters of the agent before going into the split block

Comment: Do you mean that the copy agent (from Split) retains parameters from the agent that was copied? In that case, you have to ensure the copy is the same agent type as the original, and add code to copy across parameter values via the "On exit copy" action (which gives you access to the original and the copy via local variables).

Comment: My agents have their "id" set at the source from a database. In the "on exit copy" field I have "agent.setParameter(agent.id,agent.getParameter(id))" but I keep getting id cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: The special local variables `agent` and `original` refer to the new (copy) and original agent in the "on exit copy" action block. You just set parameters directly (don't use `setParameter`) so just `agent.id = original.id;`

Comment: The lightbulb symbol next to the action block (when you have your cursor in it) tells you the local variables available to you in that block.

Comment: One problem that I run into is measuring the time in system, since they are not the same agent, it wont measure the time. Any guidelines on how to approach it?

Comment: @NasrCheaib Yes, you can't use TimeMeasureStart/End blocks here. You have to 'manually' record the entry time in the custom agent type (let's say in a variable `startTime`) and ensure that is copied across to copies (from Split); if the Combine block retains one of the original agents then it will still be there after the combine. Then you can just use `time() - agent.startTime` in the Sink block to get the time-in-system.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to dynamically setup delay duration and resources needed from within 1 Service element:

calculate the duration your agent will use in each case (painting = 5 mins, servicing = 10 mins) --> use the longer value as the service delay

Also, make the agent require 1 painter and 1 service-engineer as resources.

Only drawback: Your painter will stay for 10 mins as well.

Alternative approach would likely involve creating your own, purely agent-based setup with seizing& releasing